# Install Java Open JDK 9 32bit?

Tags: debian, jdk

I would like to install the Java Open JDK 9 and Scala 2.12.

I thought I would start with Java Open JDK, so I went to [their site](http://jdk.java.net/9/), but I can't see a download for 32bit! My Debian is a 32bit install! What am I missing here?

Also, Scala is [confusing me too](https://scala-lang.org/download/2.12.2.html), I have managed to download the `.tgz` by doing

```
wget https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.12.2/scala-2.12.2.tgz
```

Then extract it by doing

```
tar -xvzf scala-2.12.2.tgz
```

But then what? Where do I move the `scala-2.12.2` directory to? I guess the same question arises for the Java Open JDK, where do I move that too (assuming its download and extracting will yield the same thing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option to install OpenJDK 9 on Debian 9 is to use [the version available in Stretch backports](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch-backports/openjdk-9):

1. add the backports repository (as root)

   ```
   echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
   ```
2. update your package indexes

   ```
   apt update
   ```
3. install OpenJDK

   ```
   apt install -t stretch-backports openjdk-9-jdk
   ```

Note that as of this writing, this will install build 181, not the 9.0.1 release.

For Scala, you should install the upstream-provided Debian package:

```
wget https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.12.4/scala-2.12.4.deb
apt install ./scala-2.12.4.deb
```

(the package is supposed to be architecture-independent, so it should work as-is on your 32-bit system).

Comment: When I run the 3rd step, I get `E: Unable to locate package openjdk-9`

Comment: Sorry, I got the package name wrong (thanks @GAD3R!).